# Dynamically adjust an iframe's height

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, dynamic, resize

I have an iframe that contains some content from a site.  I want the iframe to adjust to 100% of the src content's height.  Bit of a noob at js - here's what I'm working with:

```
  <iframe id="frame" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" src="http://www.srcwebsite.org"></iframe>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function resizeIframe() {
        var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
        height -= document.getElementById('frame').offsetTop;

        height -= 20; /* whatever you set your body bottom margin/padding to be */

        document.getElementById('frame').style.height = height +"px";

    };
    document.getElementById('frame').onload = resizeIframe;
    window.onresize = resizeIframe;
    </script>
```

This works great to resize the height of the iframe to its page, but I want it to resize it to the height of the src...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't access the height of the `iframe`'s content because of [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) (protocol, domain and ports must match).

You could set up [CORS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing), keep in mind it's not supported in IE until IE8.