# dynamically adjusting height of div

Tags: javascript, css, xhtml

Hi I am looking for this: [Dynamically adjust an iframe's height](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7563408/dynamically-adjust-an-iframes-height) but for it to do it to a div, i have the following thus far:

```
#NewsBlock {
height: 222px;
overflow-x: auto;
padding: 5px;
}



<div class="boxFive">
<h3 class="tab">Latest News</h3>
<script type="text/javascript">
function resizeIframe() {
    var height = document.documentElement.clientHeight;
height -= document.getElementById('NewsBlock').offsetTop;

height -= 20; /* whatever you set your body bottom margin/padding to be */
document.getElementById('NewsBlock').style.height = height +"px";

};
document.getElementById('NewsBlock').onload = resizeIframe;
window.onresize = resizeIframe;
</script>
                    <div id="NewsBlock">
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="ShortNews">
                            <a href="" class="NewsLink"></a>
                            <p>title for news article<a href="#" title="Click to read more">more...</a></p>
                        </div>

                    </div>
                </div>
```

but it doesn't seem to be working, am i missing out something?

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
function resizeIframe() {
  var height = 0;
  var body = window.document.body;
  if (window.innerHeight) {
      height = window.innerHeight;
  } else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
      height = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
  } else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
      height = body.clientHeight;
  }
  document.getElementById('NewsBlock').style.height = ((height - document.getElementById('NewsBlock').offsetTop) + "px");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

put your script after NewsBlock div

Comment: I added the css change, and put the js after the NewsBlock div but no change, when i did it on http://jsfiddle.net/BWC27/ it didn't work as planned, its support to be the same size as the content text div to the right so they both finish at the same place. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your Javascript is working just fine. However, you may not be seeing the results, simply because the containing div #NewsBlock is not clipping its contents.  Try setting your css to:

```
#NewsBlock {
   height: 222px;
   overflow-x: auto;
   overflow-y: hidden;
   padding: 5px;
}
```

This worked for me, check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/zKnnQ/4/

Note that you can see the height of your container div changing if you open up a webkit console.